# Code works in Chrome v.42 but not in Chrome v.43, why?

Tags: javascript, android, google-chrome, html5-canvas

I have javascript code that runs in many different devices, browsers and versions. The four lines of code that I lists below works in Chrome v.42 running on OS X Yosemite but not in Chrome v.43 running on Android devices. The code works in Chrome v.42 on Android. I have tested this on android version 4.4 and version 5.1. This code doesn't work on Firefox for Android either. I have no real idea of what is wrong. I grasping for a straw here. Please help if you can!

```
this.canvas.drawLayer.globalCompositeOperation = 'source-in';
this.canvas.drawLayer.drawImage(this.canvas.back, rect.x, rect.y, rect.width, rect.height, rect.x, rect.y, rect.width, rect.height);
this.canvas.mainLayer.drawImage(this.canvas.draw, rect.x, rect.y, rect.width, rect.height, rect.x, rect.y, rect.width, rect.height);
this.canvas.drawLayer.globalCompositeOperation = 'source-over';
```

Comment: do you get any errors in console?

Comment: No, I don't get any errors regrettable.

Comment: Does chrome reach your code? I had a problem with the last chrome update (43) and mine was because of [this](http://updates.html5rocks.com/2015/04/DOM-attributes-now-on-the-prototype). I was getting errors on console though.

Comment: I'm not sure what you mean by your question, but if you ask me if the code is executed in the browser then I say yes, Chrome reaches the code. I can step debug the code using breakpoints. Thank you for your idea, it could have worked. :-)